# Sending mails with actionmailer (Ruby on Rails) - without SMTP?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

As the title says, is it possible to send mails without using SMTP? I've got it working by setting up SMTP, but then I need an account that I can send from and I want to be able to send mails from the website it self.

I followed this guide:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

But it won't send anything and I get this error:

```
Connection refused - connect(2)
```

Here's my code:

user_mailer.rb

```
class UserMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "noreply@example.se"

  def invitation_mail(user)
      mail(:to => "user@example.com", :subject => "Admin registration - vanadismilano.com")
  end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, "without using SMTP". You want to implement the protocol yourself?!

Comment: The thing is, according to the guide I linked I wuold be good to go after generating the actionmailer and created the method in it.

Comment: Not really, there's an [entire section on configuration](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration).

Comment: Oh snap.. Totally missed that one -.- thanks